# Symfony DIC and Parent Services not working

Tags: zend-framework, dependency-injection, symfony

I'm integrating Symfony DIC in a zend framework application, that's going fine except for parent services.

In my DIC config I have a parent service PC_Service which will be extended by all my services.
The problem is that the entity manager is not available (NULL) in the services that extend PC_Service. When I inject the entitymanager via service.stats the entitymanger is set correctly.

```
...
<service id="pc.service" class="PC_Service" abstract="true">
    <call method="setEntityManager">
        <argument type="service" id="doctrine.entitymanager" />
    </call>
</service>
...
<service id="service.stats" class="Application_Service_Stats" parent="pc.service" />
...
```

**PC_Service**

```
abstract class PC_Service
{
    protected $_em;

    public function setEntityManager($entityManager)
    {
        $this->_em = $entityManager;
    }
}
```

**Application_Service_Stats**

```
class Application_Service_Stats extends PC_Service
{
    ... $this->_em should be set here.
}
```

I hope someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: inst there an easier way to integrate doctrine into zend than using symfony2?

Comment: This isn't about integrating doctrine but about Dependency injection

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this? I'm having the same issue and am stepping through the Symfony code to figure it out (without much luck so far unfortunately)

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find a solution. It just seems to be a bug. I opened a bug report but didn't get any repsonse yet https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4098

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is to compile the service container near the end of the ZF bootstrap. This process has a step called `ResolveDefinitionTemplatesPass` which patches in the calls from parent services.

This is typically done by the [Symfony Kernel](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php#L673), but of course it isn't present in a ZF integration.

```
protected function _initServiceContainerCompilation()
{
    // Wait for the SC to get built
    $this->bootstrap('Services');

    // Doctrine modifies the SC, so we need to wait for it also
    $this->bootstrap('Doctrine');

    // Compiling the SC allows "ResolveDefinitionTemplatesPass" to run,
    // allowing services to inherit method calls from parents
    $sc = $this->getResource('Services');
    $sc->compile();
}
```

Comment: Yes, mine was initalised correctly as well, except parent calls weren't being inherited. Are you sure you're doing `ServiceContainer->compile()`? It's an extra step you need to do since you're using the SC outside of the Symfony Kernel.

Comment: If you're debugging, you could even set a breakpoint in `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ResolveDefinitionTemplatesPass->process()` to see if it's being called. That's the method responsible for managing service inheritance.

Comment: What's in your _initServices method?

Comment: Glad to help - it took me a while to figure out too!

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it's a typo but it should be `doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager` or `doctrine.orm.entity_manager` (alias of the previuos):

```
<service id="pc.service" class="PC_Service" abstract="true">
    <call method="setEntityManager">
        <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager" />
    </call>
</service>
```

Comment: doctrine.entitymanager isn't the problem. It's working fine if I inject it directly in the service.stats